# Improving SQL Server database performance

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, inner-join, database-performance

I'm designing a reporting solution which uses SQL Server 2008 R2 as its backend database. The database schema is fairly simple. One table named `Calls` with `CallId` PK and one table named `Events` which has a foreign key association to calls with `fk_CallId`.

Each call has at least 6-7 events and there are 3000+ calls per day logged in db.
I'm a bit worried about how much effect this relation has on the queries' performance. If using `inner join` on a table with more than a couple of million rows (`Events`) is going to degrade performance very much, I could add a `CallerId` field to `Events` table a do not use joins (Although I will lose some other information on related `Calls` table).

In general, Is there any other step I can do to make sure the performance is ok?

Comment: After 100 years you'll have about 100 million rows in your database. As this is still a medium sized database, I really would not worry about performance at this point. The key here is to make sure you have properly indexed your tables (and running on decent hardware offcourse).

Comment: @Lieven: Thanks for the comment. however, as I have commented in Oleg's answer, my estimation is 7,000,000+ rows in `events` table each year.

Comment: then it would become 700 million rows **after 100 years**. My original comment still applies. While I certainly encourage thinking about optimization, make sure you don't fall victim of [premature optimization](http://www.google.be/search?q=premature+optimization&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:nl:official&client=firefox-a).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on - how *wide* your tables are.

Actually - 3000 calls per day is not such a big data, at least for first ten years 8-)

**but**

if you always want to query all your data - something is wrong **by design** of application and improving performance in one particular place will not cure all the cons of wrong design.

The steps are:

- check proper indexing (at least index on joined (and queried) columns
- check your queries - do they bring to you data you want? the only data you want?

Comment: 3000 calls per day -> ~20,000 events per day -> 7,000,000+ rows per year.

Comment: So what? I work with DB which grows with 1.5 millions rows per day from the year of 2005, it works like a charm with hundreds of millions of rows and several terabytes of data. Everything depend on proper design

Comment: @Kamyar, 7,000,000 rows a year is tiny in database terms.

Comment: Come to my world. 600 million events in a database. PER DAY. ;) 7 million fit in memory on a SMALL COMPUTER.

Comment: @TomTom This is a call log or smth? What is the growth of DB per day? Just interesting.

Comment: When loading it is about 50gb per day. I actually start reworking it to keep most data out of sql because it is not used in a way that requries sql access to it. Financial level 2 information. I work on another project where we handle for a cusomer a 21tb database.... talk about hitting a database server with around 15 million sql queries in 7 minutes during load ;)

Comment: @TomTom I thought that my server is under high load 8-) In the top it has 1.5M hits per 10 min. So, now I realize, that it is medium to low load 8-)

Comment: It also likely is a much less expensive machine. We talk oracle here - not softaware. ExaData, two calculation nodes, 3 storage nodes if I remember right (thre is a sparate department dealing with the hardware). The price gets you a ferrari or something. IThink we pay half a million euro over 3 years per machine (we have 3 - production, hot standby, development) including hosting and administration. We have I think 1000gb flash write through cache combined on the storage nodes. I always laugh when people come with something like a million rows for a HUGH table.

Comment: @TomTom We also have a dedicated HW department, and I talked about 1 server from 350(physical). Our yearly upgrade cost ONLY of SAN storage sometimes hits 2.7 M$ 8-) There bunch of Ferraries, Bugatties and Veyrons here 8-) We own a separate datacenter built @ countryside, dedicated network to it and dedicated backup power plant there and cooling water supply 8-)

Comment: @TomTom Your Cache thru is built over storage stands? If yes - just like ours - over 4 node Hitachi VSP and Hitachi AMS2300 (middle tier for backup), USPVm, NSC55

Comment: Ah - no. It is included. ExaData is a very cluster technology. Databasee servers talk to storage servers that then use the cache internally (376 gb per mode, IIRC). All connected with multiple Infiniband cables. And the storage nodes prefilter returned data - all extremely optimized. The storage nodes are part of the system, not a SAN. And filter table data based on what Oracle calles a Storage Filter, taking load off the database nodes. I am a significant non fan or oracle, but the exadata architecture is seriously impressive. Sadly it is something most people never will see.

Comment: @TomTom Yup, very interesting, thanx, but - yes never seen it and guess - I'll never see (while working here), our company not using Exadata, and uses Oracle in very small and specific area